# Creating no-code website pages on a coded static website

Tags: html, wordpress, url, webflow

First time posting here so hopefully this reaches the right people.

I am looking for a solution to this on behalf of a team member. We have a static HTML website build exclusively without no-code solutions, but our marketing team would like the ability to create landing pages for marketing content that can be built on something like webflow or elementor, that then can be linked to our domain.

So an example would be that our website is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) (this is coded HTML)
The marketing team would then want to create no-code landing pages in a website builder that can be linked to [www.example.com/landingpage1](http://www.example.com/landingpage1)

Essentially, connecting our already live website, to a no-code solution to publish/create additional pages. Is something like this possible? :)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to have a sub domain pointing on Webflow like
landing.mysite.com. You can't have a subfolder pointing to Webflow.

You have to configure DNS in order to do that. The first time it's a little bit tricky. Then you configure the settings in Webflow to landing.mysite.com

And then marketing people can have fun and you keep your static site.